# Mount Windows share on Linux boot

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount, network-shares, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running VirtualBox in Windows.  I have Ubuntu Linux 10.04 installed as a VM.

Whenever I log in I have to run to following command to mount my shared Windows web dev folder:

```
sudo mount.vboxsf web_apps /mnt/web_apps
```

Where can I put this line (minus the sudo) so that it will run once when Linux boots up?  I'm guessing there must be a root .profile or .login script that runs at some point?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to The Operator I figured it out, for future superusers, here's what I did:

1. From Terminal:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modules
   ```
2. Added the following to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   vboxvfs
   vboxadd
   ```
3. Save and exit.  Then:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
4. Then, at the bottom of this file added:

   ```
   web_apps /mnt/web_apps vboxsf defaults 0 0
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the share to your /etc/fstab for it to be mounted automatically at boot.  See [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Comment: Thanks, took a bit of reading, and a little more googling, but got it sorted.  I'm updating my question with my steps.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me except I had to add a / before the "web_apps" in step 4.
The new line for me was:

> /web_apps /mnt/web_apps vboxsf defaults 0 0